# Is there a notepad++ plugin that makes JSP comments format correctly?

Tags: jsp, syntax, syntax-highlighting, notepad++

I would love [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to show the comments correctly ([see screenshot](http://i46.tinypic.com/xpww05.png))

Is there any plugin that takes care of it? Or is there any way I can get it to default to another languages' formatting when I load a JSP file?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the JSP syntax highlighter uses the VB rules between <% %> tags.

Answer (score 0):

Since [Notepad++ 5.6.5](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Releases#Version_5.6.5) which was released only 5 monts ago there's a builtin JSP syntax highlighter. Are you using the right version? If it's behaving buggy, you'd better report [a bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=95717&atid=612382) to the Notepad++ guys.

Comment: I'm using 5.6.8 and I have submitted a bug report to them. No response as far as I know...

Comment: What if you try to associate it with ASP highlighter?

Comment: Also doesn't pick up the comments?

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas other than suggesting another editor or an fullworthy IDE :) I myself use Eclipse.

Comment: Although I don't use it for JSP, I tried it in my favourite text editor [Editplus](http://www.editplus.com/) and Java comments in JSP scriptlets are shown correctly. Unrelated to the problem: raw Java code in a JSP files is considered poor practice... Learn [servlets](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html) ;)

Comment: Hi @BalusC, in Editplus, we are not able to auto-highlight the same keyword across the whole file right? Or any plugin can do that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the current JSP support is really just relabelled ASP support, so the Java specific parts of this are broken. (This also explains why if you put a single-quote in the text of a server-side comment, it highlights that part of the comment but not the rest of it.)

Because grokking a JSP file properly will require parsing some ASP-like syntax and JavaScript-like syntax this really needs to be fixed upstream in the Scintilla project.

Scintilla currently has four feature requests for this, of various vintage since 2005... and yes I know this thread is four years old, but nothing much seems to have changed. I'll have a look in my spare time at how easy it would be to enhance the cut-and-paste of ASP that's currently there into something better, starting with comments as it's annoying the heck out of me too.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a really old question, but I had the same problem and I solved it just modifying the file *style.model.xml* in the directory *Programs/Notepad++* in this way:

1. Copy and paste the node `LexerType` with `name="asp"`
2. Rename the new node with `name="jsp" desc="JSP" ext="jsp"`
3. Eventually place it in the right alphabtical order (just for finding purpose)
4. Save
5. Restart notepad++

The result should be like this:

```
<LexerType name="jsp" desc="JSP" ext="jsp">
  <WordsStyle name="DEFAULT" styleID="81" fgColor="8000FF" bgColor="C4F9FD" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
  <WordsStyle name="COMMENTLINE" styleID="82" fgColor="008000" bgColor="C4F9FD" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
  <WordsStyle name="NUMBER" styleID="83" fgColor="FF0000" bgColor="C4F9FD" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
  <WordsStyle name="WORD" styleID="84" fgColor="000080" bgColor="C4F9FD" fontName="" fontStyle="1" fontSize="" keywordClass="instre1" />
  <WordsStyle name="STRING" styleID="85" fgColor="808080" bgColor="C4F9FD" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
  <WordsStyle name="IDENTIFIER" styleID="86" fgColor="000000" bgColor="C4F9FD" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
  <WordsStyle name="ASPSYBOL" styleID="15" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFF00" fontName="" fontStyle="1" fontSize="" />
  <WordsStyle name="SCRIPTTYPE" styleID="16" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFC000" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
</LexerType>
```